# Very simple excel file to php array returns me too many nested arrays?

Tags: php, excel

**Excel file:**

[image]

**PHP code (excel to array):**

```
function excel_to_array($excel_file) {
    $filename = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/admin/user_files/' . $excel_file['name'];
    $type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($type);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);

    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        $worksheets[] = $worksheet->toArray();
    }

    var_dump($worksheets);
}
```

**Result:**

```
array (size=1)
    0 =>
        array (size=2)
            0 =>
                array (size=1)
                    0 => string '0894090592' (length=10)
            1 =>
                array (size=1)
                    0 => string '0894040404' (length=10)
```

There is too much nested arrays for such a simple excel, **I'm lookig for something like this**:

```
$worksheets = ['0894090592', '0894040404'];
```

Is there a way ?

P.S: I will NOT have multiple columns, but will have more rows, like these!

Comment: No!if you have multiple data on multiple rows and columns Which format is more easy to handle ?

Comment: Seems to be structured as `worksheet-id row-id column-id`. You will need to extract your data if you want it to look more simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting the data:

```
function excel_to_array($excel_file) {
    $filename = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/admin/user_files/' . $excel_file['name'];
    $type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($type);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);
    $worksheets = array();

    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        $worksheetArray= $worksheet->toArray();
        foreach($worksheetArray as $row) {
            if(isset($row[0])) {
                $worksheets[] = $row[0];
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($worksheets);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_column to get only the values in [0].

```
function excel_to_array($excel_file) {
    $filename = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/admin/user_files/' . $excel_file['name'];
    $type = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filename);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($type);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filename);

    foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
        $worksheets[] = $worksheet->toArray();
    }

    // Here we get only the values to a flat array
    $worksheets = array_column($worksheets, 0);
    var_dump($worksheets);
}
```